# ASP.NET Image Control Renders in wrong DOM location

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Image Control that refuses to render inside of an HTML table.

You will see in the ASPX page that the ASP.NET image control is inside of the HTML table, towards the bottom of the table, below the biography textarea.

When the page populates with data, the image is moved from inside the HTML table, to above the HTML table.

Here's the ASPX page source:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMembers" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Members: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMembers" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMembers_SelectedIndexChanged">            
                </asp:DropDownList>                
                or <asp:Button ID="btnNew" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="New Member" OnClick="btnNew_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td> 
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Repeat Password:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bio:</td>
            <td>                            
                <textarea name="txtBioEditor" id="txtblogEditor" rows="10" cols="80" runat="server"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <asp:Image ID="imgMember" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace("txtBioEditor");
    </script>
</asp:Panel>
```

In the code-behind, I am simply populating the page controls with member data from the DB when the dropdown list selected index is changed.

```
    protected void ddlMembers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMembers.SelectedValue);
        if (selectedId > 0)
        {
            Member m = new Member();
            m.GetMemberById(selectedId);
            if (m.MemberCount > 0)
            {
                txtName.Text = m.Name;
                txtEmail.Text = m.Email;
                txtblogEditor.InnerHtml = m.Biography;
                imgMember.ImageUrl = m.Image;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ClearFields();
        }
    }
```

And here is how it renders:

```
<div id="pnlMembers">   
<img id="imgMember" src="/images/member3.jpg"><table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>
            Members: 
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentAdminMain$ddlMembers" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentAdminMain$ddlMembers\',\'\')', 0)" id="ddlMembers">
                <option value="0">Select Member</option>
                <option value="1">Member 1</option>
                <option value="2">Member 2</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="3">Member 3</option>
                <option value="4">Member 4</option>
            </select>                
            or <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentAdminMain$btnNew" value="New Member" id="btnNew">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td> 
        <td><input name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentAdminMain$txtName" type="text" value="Member 3 Name" id="txtName"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentAdminMain$txtEmail" type="text" value="member3@gmail.com" id="txtEmail"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentAdminMain$txtPassword" type="password" id="txtPassword"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Repeat Password:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentAdminMain$txtPassword2" type="password" id="txtPassword2">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bio:</td>
        <td>                            
            <textarea name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentAdminMain$txtblogEditor" id="txtblogEditor" rows="10" cols="80">Member 3 Bio</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentAdminMain$btnSave" value="Save" id="btnSave">
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentAdminMain$btnCancel" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace("txtBioEditor");
</script>
```

As you can see in the rendered HTML, the image element has been taken out of the table element, and inserted above the table, in the parent div. What is going on here? I appreciate your help.

Comment: I think you might need to add td tags around your image control. It's my understand (i could be wrong) that tr tags themself don't really render content, they just allow the td tags to be rendered and positioned properly.

Comment: That's what it was. Thank you. I can't believe I didn't see that. I appreciate the second set of eyes. Thanks again!

Comment: Added it as answer, just for the xp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr>
<td>
        <asp:Image ID="imgMember" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
</td>
</tr>
```

As per my comment re rendering/positioning